# How to layer a CCSprite on top of a CCSprite?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, layer, ccsprite, cclayer

In my game, I have a series of avatars, currently each avatar has a small rectangular container to denote that this image is a button and can be clicked.

However, I've realised that I need to change the color of the container to denote a visual effect (such as the button click).

For example:

Off state = Grey container.  On state = Red container

Rather than repeating each avatar with the off/on state on, I'd like to seperate the container and the avatars, a bit like this crude drawing;

```
+------+    +------+  
|      |    |      |    O
| OFF  |    | ON   |   / \
|      |    |      |   --- 
+------+    +------+
```

Thus, we seperate the off container, the on container and the avatars.

Then, in my game I want to be able to re-construct the sprite with the layers I want to use, in addition I want the newly constructed sprite to act like a singular CCSprite, so I can position it properly, or do other things with the sprite.

Sorta like creating a CCSprite from various CCSprites layered on top of each other.

Thus, how can I layer multiple sprites on top of each other, and then create a CCSprite using layered CCSprites?

Thanks.

/Edit: Added some code.

I have created some code using CCLayer and then added my sprites as part of a layer.

```
[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] addSpriteFramesWithFile:
         @"avatars.plist"];

        CCSpriteBatchNode *spriteSheet = [CCSpriteBatchNode 
                                          batchNodeWithFile:@"avatars.png"];
        [self addChild:spriteSheet];

        CCSprite *empty = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"hold_empty.png"];
        CCSprite *boss1 = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"hold_boss_1.png"];

        CCLayer *holderExample = [[CCLayer alloc] init];
        [holderExample setContentSize:CGSizeMake(70, 72)];
        [holderExample setPosition:CGPointMake(100, 100)];
        [holderExample addChild:empty];
        [holderExample addChild:boss1];

        [self addChild:holderExample];
```

This seems to make a layer with two sprites inside it.  This seems right, but I'm not sure if this is correct because I'm not sure if I can make it clickable, or handle other events.

In addition, I'm wanting to add a layer for the color.

In Z-Order:

1) -2 empty.png

2) -1 color layer

3) 0 avatar

Comment: do you mean simply adding a CCSprite as a child of another CCSprite?

Comment: You can use the CCMenuItemImage for the Buttons and set the Enable and Disable Image..

Comment: @Ultrakome - No, I mean 3 images, (1) off state container (2) on state container (3) avatar.  Then, I layer the off/on state on top of the avatar to make a new CCSprite

Comment: @Marine - I did play a little with CCMenuItemImage for the buttons, but I wasn't sure how to layer a sprite inside it

Comment: @Ultrakorne - Imagine a stack of cards.  The first card/layer is the avatar sprite, the second card/layer is the off/on state.  The whole thing should be a CCSprite though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make images for the on/off states and add as child of a custom CCSprite that has the on, off and avatar images. Also, you can apply a color to the avatar to make the selection effect. Don't know if this is exactly what you need.

//Edit1
Check this sources and let me know if this is what you need. Is pretty simple what i did just to show you what i mean about the color. Hope this help https://rapidshare.com/files/3668681798/TestAvatar.zip

Comment: I think I have a sample (see question as I've added some code)

Comment: Just to confirm, 1. Create images for on/off states.  2. Add these as child of CCSprite.  I can do this, but I'm not sure what you mean by adding color to the avatar.  Do you mean a color layer?

Comment: You can set a color to a CCSprite, i think you can achieve the effect you want using that property. Anyway, i think you can achieve this with just the 3 images. I will try to get you a sample code.

Comment: Will do!  After some research, I do not think CCLayer is the right way to go.  The reason is because I don't think you can make CCMenuItems with layers, they have to be images or sprites.  Perhaps there is another way, I'm going to look at your source code and get back to you.

Comment: @Sentrio -- I see what you mean now, in your source code you made an Avatar button with child CCSprites inside them, which is much better because I think you should be able to use this for a CCMenuItem and I should be able to put a CCGradient color layer inside it.

Comment: @Sentrio -- That's perfect! I was able to put `CCLayerColor *lc = [CCLayerColor layerWithColor:ccc4(133, 255, 255, 255) width:65 height:70];
lc.position = ccp(2, 0);` in the avatar button and layer it properly, I even got the button to look like it was being pressed with your source code!  In addition, its much better than my CCLayer idea as it should be usable in menu items too!  Thanks a lot!

Comment: No problem, i'm glad to help you :) BTW, is setrio not sentrio xD

Comment: Opps, my mistake. Upped your answer by 1.